# How to add a "s3:ListBucket/" to give access to a bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, identity-management

Issue is IAM permissions already exist and the User x has permissions to s3:ListALLMyBuckets through identity policy, letting them return a list of all buckets owned by authenticated sender of request but missing "s3:ListBucket" action on (needed) bucket.

How can I add this permission, and should I add them to S3 or as an IAM inline policy for user?

S3 policy on needed bucket has GetObject but not ListBucket.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit the policy that's attached to the user and add the `"s3:ListBucket"` permission as you mentioned.

As per the documentation, you need to have `ListALLMyBuckets` in order for `ListBucket` to work. So you need to have both permissions.

from the documentation for `ListBucket`:

> Returns a list of all buckets owned by the authenticated sender of the
> request. To use this operation, you must have the s3:ListAllMyBuckets
> permission.

Comment: there are two permissions:

Comment: Hi, You need to have both permissions in order for `ListBucket` permnission to work

refer to the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html

Comment: there are two policies/permissions: one is s3-list-all-buckets which is attached via User group policy so that I think I can't edit. Another option is to directly edit the S3 bucket policy (for bucket that needs access) that has "Action": "s3:GetObject" and I can edit it to add "s3:ListBucket". It will look like "Action": "s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket",